# Confused on assigning objects probabilities because of Set theory

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

After learning Set theory, I have a found a deep appreciation for probability but I am currently confused when I went back to review probability. I'll give a very simple example to pinpoint the confusion.

Suppose we toss a fair coin twice. What's the probability of getting a head?

The sample space is S={ HH, TT, HT, TH}. But {TH}= {HT} in Set theory? Why is it that in probability we treat HT and TH as distinct objects? Is it because order is involved i.e. the first coin toss is different from the second?

Comment: TH is understood as a sequence, not a two-element set. Thus TH is distinguished from HT. Even in set theory you can separate these; for instance you can identify $(a,b):=\{ a,\{ a,b \} \}$.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out my mistakes! I'll keep this in mind now.

Answer (score 0):

Your "abused" notation and confused yourself…

The sample space is $$\Omega = \{H,T\}^2 = \left\{(\omega_1,\omega_2), \omega_i \in \{H,T\}, i \in \{1,2\}\right\}$$

And obviously $$\{(H,T)\} \not= \{(T,H)\}$$ because $$(H,T) \not= (T,H)$$